# How to download all files from web URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I want to get all files from URL. files may be different types of extensions.

How I get all files with webclient object from Website URL.
when I open website Url then files listed as below format

- ...
- Frame.js
- MyFile.png
- Class1.cs

"Files and folder list from web URL"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write yourself a very simple web crawler. Google for 'C# web crawler' and you will find a number of blogs with simple implementations such as this one:

[How To: Write a Crawler in C#](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToWriteAWebCrawlerInCSharp.aspx)

Comment: Have you created any crawler in C#?

Answer (score 4):

As I can see your platform is Windows. If you are just looking for a tool to download all the files please look at wget in http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/.

A simple usage:

```
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p <url>
```