# download html page with all it content

Tags: asp.net, html, download

Can I download some html page with all it content (images,scripts .. etc) as list of files
or single web archive?This gives me only markup:

```
      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.youtube.com", @"D:\anyfile.html");
          //or
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.yotube.com");
          // save htmlcode ...
        }
```

May be there are any API?

Comment: if this is a one-off download you can use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) to download a given site

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724960/how-to-download-all-files-from-web-url

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will only give you markup because that's all that's returned from the URL you provided.

In order to access all the other referenced resources, you'll need to do some parsing of the markup and get the URLs for those resources.

Comment: arent there any existing librarys?

Comment: I'm pretty certain there is nothing in .NET that does anything like this. Of course, it's impossible to confirm no one else has written such code and made it available as a library.